# Android Library integration and APP size

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am using the [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) library,and integrated it via build.gradle as normally suggested. 
But since the library classes are locked this way and I want to be able to edit every class manually I have the following questions.

**1.** What is the go to way of including a library such as [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) in a way
that I will be able to edit every class.

**2.** Since I want to minimize the final size of my Android App, does different integration of librarys have an impact here or does the magic during build process exclude stuff that is not needed ?

I am simply not surf if downloading the complete github .zip is necessary or even the right way to do it, since it also includes a sample app and other unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is the go to way of including a library such as AppIntro in a way that I will be able to edit every class.

Grab the sources and add to your project **as separate module**.

> 2. Since I want to minimize the final size of my Android App, does different integration of libraries have an impact here or does the
>      magic during build process exclude stuff that is not needed

ProGuard shall strip all the library code (but also your own code too :) that are not referenced (that's why it's important to sometimes tell it not do to that if you i.e. need code that rely on reflection to work.

Comment: Thank you, I also found this: http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/ . I guess this is what u meant by "Grab the sources and add to your project as separate module."

Comment: Basically yes. Or you create the module by hand and copy source files. Does not matter really how you do this, but the whole trick here is to have it in separate module, instead of merging in into your "app" module code.